# Sharepoint 2007: Two entire site collections went read-only overnight, the other 5 are fine

Tags: security, sharepoint-2007, permissions, sharepoint

Myself and a coworker are both Site Admins for every site collection we've got.  Well, until Friday night.  Most admin privileges were disabled for two entire site collections.  There is no custom code running anywhere in MOSS, and there are no workflows set up at all.

On both of the affected site collections, my Site Actions menu shows these options:

- View All Site Content
- View Reports

  - Checked Out To Me
  - Last Modified By Me
  - Pending Approval
  - My Tasks
  - All Draft Documents
  - Going Live Within Next Seven Days
  - Expiring Within Next Seven Days
- Manage Content and Structure

We were thinking it was some sort of licensing issue where an expired license key simply removes admin privileges (allowing your content to sill be accessible) while not allowing you to edit stuff.

Here's the site collection layout:

- Root site collection (still have access)

  - Site Collection 1 (no access)
  - Site Collection 2 (no access)
  - Site Collection 3 (still have access)
  - Site Collection the rest (still have access)

I ran the enumsites operation of stsadm on the root site collection, and the output shows that my coworker is the owner and I am secondary owner (Admin and Secondary Admin match in Central Administration for all site collections).  It matches the output from two weeks ago exactly (I have it to compare to).

Any ideas?  Other spots I should check within Central Admin?

Comment: Fixed.  We don't have any quotas turned on, but somehow those two site collections got locked.  Central Administration -> Application Management -> Site Collection Quotas and Locks.  The "Site Lock Information" setting was set to Read-only for both site collections.  No clue how it happened, but when we set both back to "Not locked", we regained privileges.

Comment: please create an answer with this information and accept it, that way people know the question has been properly answered.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed. We don't have any quotas turned on, but somehow those two site collections got locked. Central Administration -> Application Management -> Site Collection Quotas and Locks. The "Site Lock Information" setting was set to Read-only for both site collections. No clue how it happened, but when we set both back to "Not locked", we regained privileges.

---

Originally added as a comment by [minameismud](https://serverfault.com/users/54741/minameismud). Relocated his update to an answer so this question no longer shows up as unanswered.